# Combination keys (Ctrl + Alt + F6) AutoIt X3

Tags: c#, winforms, autoit-c#-wrapper

I am trying to send a key stroke to my application. I can send keystrokes like <kbd>F3</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd> but I am unable to send combined keystrokes. This is the code im using to send a keystroke :

```
 ControlSend(strings.TerminalName, "", "SysListView321", "^!{F6}");
```

as I know:

> ^ = ctrl
>   ! = alt

I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

this code

```
  ControlSend(strings.TerminalName, "", "SysListView321", "^!{F6}");
```

should be changed to this

```
  ControlSend(strings.TerminalName, "", "SysListView321", "^!!{F6}");
```

I needed to send double !!.. :-)